# MIMO (multi input - multi output) system decoupling method

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, systems-engineering

A **MIMO** system with 2 input and 2 output **decoupling** method to a **SISO** system is described in many articles and books. How about **m*n size transfer functions** systems? How can we generalize the method for example to 3*3 or 3*7 MIMO systems?

Here is a 2*2 MIMO system description:

> [image]
>
> with $\mathrm{D_{11}(s)=D_{22}(s)=1}$ to the form
>
> $$\mathrm{D(s)}=\begin{bmatrix} D_{11}(s) & D_{12}(s) \\ D_{21}(s) &
> > D_{22}(s) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Here we specify a decoupled response and the decoupler with the
>   structure in Equation
>
> $$G_p(s)D(s)=\begin{bmatrix} G_{11}(s) & 0 \\0 & G_{22}(s)
> > \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} G_{11}(s) & G_{12}(s) \\ G_{21}(s) &
> > G_{22}(s) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & D_{12}(s) \\ D_{21}(s) & 1
> > \end{bmatrix}
> > = \begin{bmatrix} G^*_{11}(s) & 0 \\ 0 & G^*_{22}(s) \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> And we can solve four equations in four unknowns to find
>
> $$D_{12}(s) = -\frac{G_{12}(s)}{G_{11}(s)} \\ D_{21}(s) =
> > -\frac{G_{21}(s)}{G_{22}(s)} \\ G_{l1}(s) = G_{11}(s) = -\frac{G_{12}(s)G_{21}(s)}{G_{22}(s)} \\ G_{l2}(s) = G_{22}(s) = -\frac{G_{21}(s)G_{12}(s)}{G_{11}(s)} $$

Comment: You need to be looking in possibly a network analysis and synthesis textbooks, eg Kuo, or Brian D.O. Anderson & Sumeth Vongpanitlerd. It's not a subject that is taught much these days.

Comment: I think that you are looking for the state space form.

Comment: This topic on the math stackexchange might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297659/relative-gain-array-of-a-singular-matrix

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you the solution by using transfer functions. However I can give you a general form by using the state space representation. I will do it for a **square** system, i.e. the number of inputs and outputs is equal. For a system with $n$ inputs and $m$ outputs it is getting more messy and a lot harder to solve the problem.

The system
$$\dot{x}=f(x)+ g_1(x)u_1 + \ldots + g_m(x)u_m$$
with outputs
$$y_1 = h_1(x), \ldots, y_m = h_m(x)$$

First introducing the Lie Derivative. The Lie Derivative of $h$ with respect to $f$ or along $f$ is
$$L_{f}h(x) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}f(x)$$
For example, the following notation is used:
$$\begin{split} 
L_g L_f &= \frac{\partial (L_f h)}{\partial x}g(x)\\
L_f^2 h(x) &= L_f L_f h(x) &= \frac{\partial (L_f h)}{\partial x}f(x)\\
L_f^kh(x) &= L_f L_f^{k-1}h(x) &= \frac{\partial (L_f^{k-1})}{\partial x}f(x)
 \end{split}$$

Introducing the notion of relative degree with respect to each output.
Consider the $i$-th output and differentiate it with respect to time:
$$\dot{y}_i = L_fh_i(x) +L_{g_1}h_i(x)u_1 +\ldots L_{g_m}h_i(x)u_m$$
This expression depends explicitly on at least one input if (for all $x$):
$$\left(L_{g_1}h_i(x),\ldots,L_{g_m}h_i(x) \right)\neq (0,\ldots,0)$$
If so, the $i$-th output has relative degree $k_i = 1$.

In general the relative degree $k$ per output $i$ if
$$\left(L_g,L_f^{k_i-1}h_i(x),\ldots,L_{g_m}L_f^{k_i-1}h_i(x)\right) \neq (0,\ldots,0)$$ 
for all $x$.

The system is now Input-Output Linearised (hence decoupled) when applying the following feedback
$$u(x) = -A^{-1}(x)N(x)+A^{-1}(x)v$$
with the decoupling matrix $A(x)$, vector $N(x)$ and new input vector $v$.
Where
$$A(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
L_{g_1}L_f^{k_1-1}h_1(x) & \ldots & L_{g_m}L_f^{k_1-1}h_1\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
L_{g_1}L_f^{k_m-1}h_m(x) & \ldots & L_{g_m}L_F^{k_m-1}h_m\\
\end{pmatrix},\quad
N(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
L_f^{k_1}h_1(x)\\
\vdots\\
L_f^{k_m}h_m(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$.

Hence $A(x)$ needs to be invertible for all $x$. If you want the transfer functions, simply apply Laplace.